# Printing characters(with delay) on the same widget multiple times in Tkinter

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, textbox, output, python-3.7

I'm trying to print with delay (one character appears, a few milliseconds pass and then the next one appears) on the same widget multiple times one after the other, being something like >text appears with delay > a second passes> more text appears with delay... and so on. time.sleep() doesn't seems to work and i don't know how to properly use .after()

Here's the code i'm using

```
from tkinter import *

def insert_slow(widget, string):
    if len(string) > 0:
        widget.insert(END, string[0])

    if len(string) > 1:
        widget.after(50, insert_slow, widget, string[1:])

root=Tk()

tx=Text(root)

tx.pack()
insert_slow(tx, "this is a testing piece of text\n")
tx.after(3000)
loop=insert_slow(tx, "this is another testing piece of text")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `after(3000)` is almost exactly the same as `time.sleep` -- it freezes the whole UI.

The solution is pretty simple: use `after` to call your second `insert_slow`.

```
insert_slow(tx, "this is a testing piece of text\n")
tx.after(3000, insert_slow, tx, "this is another testing piece of text")
```

However, you need to be aware that `after` is relative to the time that you call `after`. Since the second line of code in the above example runs just a millisecond after the first, the second invocation won't happen 3 seconds after the first string appears, it will happen 3 seconds after it *starts* to appear.

If you want to wait for the first one to finish and *then* wait three seconds, you'll either have to do the math yourself (add 50ms times the number of characters to the starting value), or add some other mechanism. You could pass multiple strings to `insert_slow`, and it could automatically wait three seconds between each string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is executing the both texts in parallel so you get this output:

```
text1 = 'Hi to you'
text2 = 'Hi to me'

OUTPUT:
HHii  tt  oo  ymoeu
```

Your **insert_slow** behaves well but you dont need to use **after()** again if you try to run text in two separate lines.

And if so, this should be on a different new text widget.

This code works if you want to output text **on the same widget:**

```
from tkinter import *

def insert_slow(widget, string):
    if len(string) > 0:
        widget.insert(END, string[0])

    if len(string) > 1:
        widget.after(50, insert_slow, widget, string[1:])

root=Tk()

tx=Text(root)
tx.pack()

text_body = "this is a testing piece of text\n" \
            "this is another testing piece of text"



insert_slow(tx, text_body)

root.mainloop()
```

if you want the text lines to insert slow together, you can use this also:

```py
from tkinter import *

def insert_slow(widget, string):
    if len(string) > 0:
        widget.insert(END, string[0])

    if len(string) > 1:
        widget.after(50, insert_slow, widget, string[1:])

root=Tk()

tx1=Text(root)
tx2=Text(root)
tx1.pack()
tx2.pack()

text_body1 = "this is a testing piece of text\n"
text_body2 = "this is another testing piece of text"



insert_slow(tx1, text_body1)
insert_slow(tx2, text_body2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ohhh, thanks a lot for Your help, it works just fine :333